# Estimate the ranking of a person's College Entrance Exams grade

Tags: statistics, problem-solving, interpolation

Suppose we have a set $A$ of $84965$ integers. The distribution of $A$ is supposed to be a normal distribution with Expectation of $500$ and Standard Deviation of $100$ theoretically. However, it is just a theoretical assumption, wether it is indeed a normal distribution is unknown.

Information we already know:

> Out of the $84965$ integers, $120$ of them are greater than or equal to $800$, $2017$ of them are greater than or equal to $700$, and $14018$ of them are greater than or equal to $600$.

The question is:

> If we know a person's College Entrance Exams grade is $722$, can we estimate the person's ranking according to this grade?
> In other words, can we estimate how many of the $84965$ integers
> are greater than or equal to $722$?

And please show your reasoning of estimation.

B.t.w., my estimation of the ranking is about $1100$ - $1200$, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Let's check if it is indeed the theoretical distribution:

- $120 / 84965 \approx 0.14\% $ which is close to the expected $0.15\%$
- $2017 / 84965 \approx 2.38\%$ which is close to the expected $2.5\%$
- $14018 / 84965 \approx 16.49\%$ which is close to the expected $16\%$

So it is a fair assumption that A follows that distribution. Now let's apply a common transform: since $A \sim N(500, 100), Z = \frac{A - 500}{100}$ follows a standard normal distribution, $Z \sim N(0,1)$. For $A = 500$ we need $\phi (2,22)$ which can be found in precalculated tables about $N(0,1)$. Given that the probability that a person's grade is $722$ is now known, I will let you finish the estimation.

Comment: According to this method, the estimation is about 1122. However , this method have some systematic bias, e.g., with this method:


The estimated ranking of grade 600 is about 13484, but it is actually 14018;


The estimated ranking of grade 700 is about 1937, but it is actually 2017;


The estimated ranking of grade 800 is about 110, but it is actually 120;

Comment: The pattern is, the estimated value is always less than the actual value.

Comment: The bias is actually expected. For example, assume that there are 100 people with a score of 722. How you will you sort them? One way to explain the error is that you are practically discretize the distribution, eg there are no scores .5, so a score $\ge 721$ is the same as $\ge 722.7$ or $\ge 721.8484...$

Comment: My point is, for a set of  estimations, if some errors are positive and some errors are negative, it is good. But if all the errors are negative, maybe there is some problem.

Comment: B.t.y.," 2017/84965≈2.38%  which is close to the expected 2.5%",  according to my calculation, the expected value for score 700 is 2.3%. 
120/84965≈0.14%  which is close to the expected 0.15%. According to my calculation, the expected value for score 800 is 0.13%. 
Refer to: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html

Comment: I didn't use the actual numbers but the ones from the empirical rule.